# Connecting docker containers using external network

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am working on a micro-service architecture where we have many different projects and all of them connect to the same redis instance. I want to move this architecture to the Docker to run on development environment. Since all of the projects have separate repositories I can not just simply use one `docker-compose.yml` file to connect them all. After doing some research I figured that I can create a shared external network to connect all of the projects, so I have started by creating a network:

`docker network create common_network`

I created a separate project for common services such as mongodb, redis, rabbitmq (The services that is used by all projects). Here is the sample docker-compose file of this project:

```
version: '3'
services:
  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    container_name: test_project_redis
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    networks:
      - common_network

networks:
  common_network:
    external: true
```

Now when I run `docker-compose build` and `docker-compose up -d` it works like a charm and I can connect to the redis from my local machine using 127.0.0.1:6379. But there is a problem when I try to connect to this redis container from an other container.

Here is an other sample docker-compose.yml for another project which runs Node.js (I am not putting Dockerfile since it is irrelevant for this issue)

```
version: '3'
services:
  api:
  build: .
  container_name: sample_project_api
  networks:
    - common_network

networks:
  common_network:
    external: true
```

There is no problem when I build and run this docker-compose as well but the  Node.js project is getting `CONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379` error, which obviously it can not connect to the Redis server over 127.0.0.1

So I opened a live ssh into the api container (`docker exec -i -t sample_project_api /bin/bash`) and installed `redis-tools` to make some tests.

When I try to ping the `redis-cli ping` it returns `Could not connect to Redis at 127.0.0.1:6379: Connection refused`.

I checked the external network to see if all of the containers are connected to it properly, using `docker network inspect common_network`. There were no problem, all of the containers were listed under Containers, and from there I noticed that `sample_project_redis` container had an ip address of `192.168.16.3`
As a final solution I tried to use internal ip address of the redis container:

From sample_project_api container I run `redis-cli -h 192.168.16.3 ping` and it return with PONG which it worked.
So my problem is that I can not connect to the redis server from other containers using ip address of `127.0.0.1` or `0.0.0.0` but I can connect using `192.168.16.3` which changes every time I restart docker container. What is the reason behind this ?

Comment: (If you don’t mind manually `docker build`ing each service’s image, you can have a single `docker-compose.yml` that launches the whole thing and has only `image:` type services.)

Comment: @DavidMaze I don't think that layout will scale well and automated easily since each project is a standalone app, they should have separate docker-compose files.I will make a bash script to download, build and run common docker services (db, redis etc.) if they are not already build. This script will be run every time i want to start a standalone app using docker-compose.

Comment: If you're thinking at that scale, you also might research [tag:kubernetes] and its associated Helm deployment tool...though it's _much_ heavier-weight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Containers have a namespaced network. Each container has its own loopback interface and an ip for the container per network you attach to. Therefore loopback or 127.0.0.1 in one container is that container and not the redis ip. To connect to redis, use the service name in your commands, which docker will resolve to the ip of the container running redis:

```
redis:6379
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I am asking out of curiosity, is there a way to list all of the namespaced networks in the docker container.

Comment: Outside of the container, you can inspect the container or inspect each network (`docker container inspect ...` and `docker network inspect ...`). Inside a container you can use standard networking commands like `ip a` to show all interfaces.